# Constructive logic and Russell's paradox

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations, constructive-mathematics

To show that "naive set theory" doesn't work, Russell devised the famous example of the set $$A := \{ x \ | \ x  \not\in x \},$$ which turns out can't be a set after all, because either

- $A \in A$, but then by the property of all members of $A$ it follows that $A \not\in A$
- $A \not\in A$, but then again $A$ has to be a member of $A$, so $A \in A$.

Since both of these options yield a contradiction, $A$ can't be a set. But as I understand the whole premise of constructive logic is that it isn't valid to assume that either $A \in A$ or $A \not\in A$ has to hold.

On the other hand, by the above we have shown that $A \in A \iff A \not\in A$, which even in constructive logic can't hold.

So is Russell's paradox valid in constructive logic?

Comment: Although there is already a good accepted answer, I feel tempted to point out that you've almost answered your own question. If you just forget about the "because either" above the two bullet points, you can simply consider these as facts you've proven (constructively) from the definition of $A$. Thus you've shown $A \in A \iff A \notin A$, which as you said yourself "in constructive logic can't hold", i.e. implies $\bot$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can formulate the proof constructively as follows.  Suppose $A\in A$.  Then by definition of $A$, we conclude that $\neg(A\in A)$, which is a contradiction.  Since the assumption $A\in A$ led to a contradiction, we conclude $\neg(A\in A)$ (note that this is still valid constructively--constructively, $\neg p$ means the same thing as $p\rightarrow\bot$).

But now since $\neg(A\in A)$, the definition of $A$ implies that $A\in A$.  Thus we have reached a contradiction.